# What does " won't have...!" mean?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "won't have" in the following sentence (Source:When Randolph turned rotten by Charise Mericle Harper),

> Randolph was very pleased with what he had done. IVY **won't have** any
>   fun!
>
> ?

There is an exclamation mark in the sentence. What kind of nuance does "won't have" have in the sentence with this exclamation mark(!)?

Does "IVY won't have any fun!" mean "Randolph wish that IVY dose not have a good time" Or "Randolph think that IVY dose not have a good time"?

Looking at the dictionary, "won't have" means:

Dictinary: ==>
someone won’t have something - definition and synonyms
used for saying that someone does not allow something.

if so, does "IVY won't have any fun!" mean "IVY does not allow any fun"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you must be aware, *won't* is [a contraction of *will not.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/won't) Here, Randolph, *in his mind*, thinks that Ivy *will not have* any fun. Ivy is going on a trip without him and she says that she'd miss Randolph.

However, my answer is *general,* and without any further context, it would be difficult to comment on *What had Randolph done that made him happy?*